# laravel return 503 after composer update

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 with nginx server. I just updated server with this command

```
composer update
```

but I'm getting 503 http response code. what should I do? I know that server is running properly and there should be sth with Laravel

Comment: Is there anything in your laravel logs to state why? Chances are you've updated a dependancy package and it's now causing your application to break

Comment: Are you sure that nginx are running for site? 503 it's a internal porblem of nginx not issue of Laravel. try read error log of nginx site and paste it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

503 Error response code means that your laravel project is under maintenance.

Issue this command to up your project:

```
php artisan up
```